# Can joystick/gamepad events be captured in the X11 event loop?

Tags: c, x11, xlib, joystick

Win32 has the winmm library, which allows joystick events to be captured in the regular event loop (alongside the general window events, keyboard events, and mouse events).

Is there a similar setup in Xlib? Is my only choice to do raw input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the answer is no (until someone smarter than me comes along and corrects me). I need to do raw input. I have to poll at a reasonable interval and convert deltas into my own events.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a joystick here, but try "xev" and see if the joystick generates any events. If not you must either user raw input or some gaming library.